# property enabled of button in uialertview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I create a uialertview with two button and a textfield, and I want a disable the button "Ok" if the textfield is empty. How I can get the uibutton object, to change is enabled status.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `enabled` property inherited from [`UIControl`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIControl):

```
for(UIView *view in alertView.subviews) {
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
      ((UIButton *) view).enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

For the sake of reusability, this becomes even simpler when you have a category on `NSArray` which retrieves objects of a given class:

```
@implementation NSArray (JRAdditions)

- (NSArray *)objectsOfClass:(Class)cls {
   NSParameterAssert(cls);
   NSMutableArray *array = [@[] mutableCopy];
   for(id obj in self) if([obj isKindOfClass:cls]) [array addObject:obj];
   return [array copy];
}

@end
```

Your code can now look like this:

```
[[alertView.subviews objectsOfClass:[UIButton class]] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIButton *obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    obj.enabled = NO;
}];
```

Comment: a method like viewAtIndex don't exist?

Comment: @alex If you need to retrieve a view at a specified index, you can use `[[view subviews] objectAtIndex:someIndex]`

Comment: +1 for this answer because it's a good solution for those who are writing ease-of-use functions that need functionality without requiring the calling classes to be delegates and provide their own delegate functions (in this case `alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:`). Additionally, if you have multiple buttons and need a specific one, `if ([((UIButton *)view).titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Middle Button"]` makes a good second if-check.

Comment: Nice Answer, +1 for you...!

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 5, you can do this in the UIAlertViewDelegate instance.

```
-(BOOL) alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
   return [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text length] > 0;
}
```